# Cython Damerau-Levenshtein speed-up

Tags: python, string-matching, cython

I have the following cython implementation of calculating the Damerau–Levenshtein distance of 2 strings, based on [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance), but currently it is too slow for my needs. I have a list of about 600000 strings and I have to find typos in that list.

I would be glad if anyone could suggest any algorithmic improvements or some python/cython  magic that could reduce the runtime of the script. I don't really care about how much space it uses only the time it takes to calculate.

According to profiling the script using about 2000 strings it spends 80% of the complete runtime (24 of 30 sec) in the `damerauLevenshteinDistance` function, and I'm all out of ideas how to make it faster.

```
def damerauLevenshteinDistance(a, b, h):
    """
    a = source sequence
    b = comparing sequence
    h = matrix to store the metrics (currently nested list)
    """
    cdef int inf,lena,lenb,i,j,x,i1,j1,d,db
    alphabet = getAlphabet((a,b))
    lena = len(a)
    lenb = len(b)
    inf = lena + lenb + 1
    da = [0 for x in xrange(0, len(alphabet))]
    for i in xrange(1, lena+1):
        db = 0
        for j in xrange(1, lenb+1):
            i1 = da[alphabet[b[j-1]]]
            j1 = db
            d = 1
            if (a[i-1] == b[j-1]):
                d = 0
                db = j
            h[i+1][j+1] = min(
                h[i][j]+d,
                h[i+1][j]+1,
                h[i][j+1]+1,
                h[i1][j1]+(i-i1-1)+1+(j-j1-1)
            )
        da[alphabet[a[i-1]]] = i
    return h[lena+1][lenb+1]

cdef getAlphabet(words):
    """
    construct an alphabet out of the lists found in the tuple words with a
    sequential identifier for each word
    """
    cdef int i
    alphabet = {}
    i = 0
    for wordList in words:
        for letter in wordList:
            if letter not in alphabet:
                alphabet[letter] = i
                i += 1
    return alphabet
```

Comment: If you're willing to use Cython, coding the function in C would probably lead to a great improvement.

Comment: How long, in average, are the strings you are comparing? If they are short, your goal is to reduce the constant time factor of each operation and most answers already given apply. On the other hand, the algorithm itself is O(n^3), so optimizing against long strings will require a different strategy, mostly by _not_ calculating things far from the diagonal. Look for lazy evaluation and promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for longer strings you should get better performance by using a different algorithm that doesn't have to calculate all the values in the lena⋅lenb Matrix. For example it might often not be necessary to calculate the exact cost of the `[lena][0]` corner of the matrix, which represents the cost of starting by deleting all characters in `a`.

A better algorithm might be to always look at the point with the lowest weight calculated so far, and then go one step further in all directions from there. This way you might reach the target location without examining all locations in the matrix:

An implementation of this algorithm could use a priority queue and would look like this:

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush

def distance(a, b):
   pq = [(0,0,0)]
   lena = len(a)
   lenb = len(b)
   while True:
      (wgh, i, j) = heappop(pq)
      if i == lena and j == lenb:
         return wgh
      if i < lena:
         # deleted
         heappush(pq, (wgh+1, i+1, j))
      if j < lenb:
         # inserted
         heappush(pq, (wgh+1, i, j+1))
      if i < lena and j < lenb:
         if a[i] == b[i]:
            # unchanged
            heappush(pq, (wgh, i+1, j+1))
         else:
            # changed
            heappush(pq, (wgh+1, i+1, j+1))
      # ... more possibilities for changes, like your "+(i-i1-1)+1+(j-j1-1)"
```

This is just a rough implementation, it could be improved a lot:

- When adding new coordinates to the queue, check:

  - If the coordinates have already been processed before, don't add them again
  - If the coordinates are currently in the queue, only keep the instance with the better attached weight
- Use a priority queue implemented in C instead of the `heapq` module

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could statically type more of your code than you currently are, which would increase the speed.

You might also check out an implementation of the Levenshtein Distance in Cython as an example:
http://hackmap.blogspot.com/2008/04/levenshtein-in-cython.html

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the biggest improvement in your current code would come from using a C array instead of a list of lists for the `h` matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Run it through "cython -a", that will give you an HTML annotated source version with nicely yellow annotated lines. The darker the colour, the more Python operations are happening in that line. That usually helps quite a bit in finding time consuming object conversions and the like.

However, I'm pretty sure it will turn out that the biggest problem is your data structure. Consider using NumPy arrays instead of nested lists, or just use a dynamically allocated C memory block.

Answer (score 0):

If several words comes back in your search (if you need to calculate the Damerau Levenshtein Distance several times for the same value of the input strings), you can consider using a Dictionary (or hashmap) to cache your results. Here is an implementation in C#:

```
    private static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> DamerauLevenshteinDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>();

    public static int DamerauLevenshteinDistanceWithDictionaryCaching(string word1, string word2)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> word1Dictionary;

        if (DamerauLevenshteinDictionary.TryGetValue(word1.GetHashCode(), out word1Dictionary))
        {
            int distance;

            if (word1Dictionary.TryGetValue(word2.GetHashCode(), out distance))
            {
                // The distance is already in the dictionary
                return distance;
            }
            else
            {
                // The word1 has been found in the dictionary, but the matching with word2 hasn't been found.
                distance = DamerauLevenshteinDistance(word1, word2);
                DamerauLevenshteinDictionary[word1.GetHashCode()].Add(word2.GetHashCode(), distance);
                return distance;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // The word1 hasn't been found in the dictionary, we must add an entry to the dictionary with that match.
            int distance = DamerauLevenshteinDistance(word1, word2);
            Dictionary<int, int> dictionaryToAdd = new Dictionary<int,int>();
            dictionaryToAdd.Add(word2.GetHashCode(), distance);
            DamerauLevenshteinDictionary.Add(word1.GetHashCode(), dictionaryToAdd);
            return distance;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recently open-sourced a Cython implementation of the Damerau-Levenshtein algorithm. I include both the pyx and C source.

https://github.com/gfairchild/pyxDamerauLevenshtein